# Dummy tabs functionality that link to another site

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce, tabs

I came across an example of having tabs at the very top of the page that links to other urls. However, once you land on the other site, the relevant tab is styled as active. What are the generic thoughts if this is user friendly UX or could it be misleading?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user, I expect the tabs on the header to show sections within the site. In this case tabs are somewhat misleading and occupy a significant part of the header.

Presenting tabs as separate, simpler element could be more appropriate.

Other brands - **Brand Logo** | **Brand Logo** | **Brand Logo**

However, some sites require it by design. For example Envato market, where each links leads to a different site.

[image]